# featuring comment authors and news writers. sql

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, dml

I have a problem displaying news writers and comment writers, what happens between news writers and comment writers is the same value, it should be different, help me solve this problem

```
select a.user_id as id_user_in_post , a.nama_lengkap as author_post, b.post_sentence, c.userpost_id as id_user_in_coment, a.nama_lengkap as author_coment , c.komentar_post_sentence
FROM tbl_user a JOIN tbl_post b 
ON a.user_id=b.user_id
JOIN tbl_komentar_post c 
ON a.user_id=c.userpost_id
```

[image]

[image]

the values in id_user_in_post and id_user_in_coment should be different

Comment: How can a.user_id and c.userpost_id be different if that's what you're joining on?

Comment: because users who write news and users who comment have different IDs or different users

Comment: Right, but your JOIN is using those IDs to join the tables. If you do a join on two props, those props are by definition going to be the same. Are you wanting to JOIN table c on some kind of article ID instead?